# JavaScript + jQuery Reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find myself always using Google to look up a JavaScript or jQuery method, which takes me to either jQuery's documentation or W3Schools JavaScript reference. I would prefer something like [Rails' documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/). Are there any sites out there that make it easy to browse and search both the JavaScript and jQuery core APIs? (Bonus points if it has cross-browser support notes.)

Comment: jQuery inherently provides cross-browser support.

Comment: never ever use W3Schools! They are full with wrong syntax, old and deprecated methods etc.!

Comment: Thanks @EricJ., but I'm referring to documentation, not jQuery itself.

Comment: @mercsen But their SEO is so good. :D

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) is the go-to reference for vanilla JavaScript, but it can be hard to read, especially for new developers. Frankly, although I hate to admit it, w3schools is a lot easier for a beginner to learn from, despite its occasional inaccuracies -- just don't use it as a reference.

Comment: I doubt there would be any single resource that combines both docs. They're different concerns. It's not like jQuery is a JavaScript standard library *(thank goodness)*. The jQuery docs are usually suitable enough. JavaScript is a little tougher. I don't know of any really, nice, clean, complete resource. MDN is alright, but IMO not the best layout, and is sometimes flawed, incomplete or has broken links. W3Schools has a nicer layout, but has historically had content issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you know of this?

**http://jqapi.com/**

For browser support you need this:

**http://caniuse.com/**

JQuery 1.9 has support for all browser till ie6, 2.0 is only ie9+

Comment: Just because I think its worth mentioning it: http://www.overapi.com

Comment: Thanks, @Jessica! I didn't know about jQAPI. I'll be using it unless someone else knows of a consolidated reference.

Comment: I'd answer the question myself, but it looks like people don't think this is fit for StackOverflow. A coworker just pointed me to http://kapeli.com/dash